# unsetting cookie getting Undefined index

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

test.php

```
<?php
setcookie('username', 'mary', time()+1000);


setcookie('username', 'mary', time()-1000);


 ?>
```

view.php

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['username'];


?>
```

Error I am getting after unsetting cookie

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Users\joe\Documents\Discrete Math\xampp\htdocs\view.php on line 3

Comment: That's what you should be getting, isn't it? You are, after all, _unsetting_ it. [see?](http://www.ideone.com/MOdZo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining a cookie only to immediately unset it. Calling [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on *username* with a negative time is [essentially calling `unset($_COOKIE['username'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#example-3760) (therefore, the index in the cookie superglobal is no longer, and thus the undefined error).

I call this [expected behavior](http://www.ideone.com/MOdZo).

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting a cookie, it is like a variable, it is no more existed.
Is is list.

```
$a = 1;
$a = null;

print $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you unset the cookie, the cookie is gone, therefore the $_COOKIE array wont have this specific cookie key in it anymore.

You might want to check wheter the key exists before you actually use the key.
You can do this by using the function array_key_exists ( http://php.net/array_key_exists )

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie()` doesn't always necessarily mean that you are setting the cookie to a certain value. It simply tells PHP to update that cookie entry in the Cookies header sent back to the UserAgent. If the agent sees that the time of expiry (last parameter in `setcookie()`) has passed, it will assume the cookie has expired and will delete it. Ergo, the cookie will be deleted. Trying to access an invalid key from an array will always generate a notice in PHP. You should fix it if you can with `isset()` but on a production box you can simply just hide errors/warnings/notices or log them to a private file.

Answer (score -1):

I'ld say, work as designed. To disable these kinds of warnings, use:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Or

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ~ E_WARN); // or some other (combination of) flag(s).
```

Comment: this is really a bad solution. he should learn to avoid making errors or to produce good code. this is just masquerading

Comment: Agreed. Just because they're not fatal errors doesn't mean they should remain suppressed and unremedied.

Comment: In Tim's defense, while you should check if the array index is defined, on a live server it is encouraged to not display errors, warnings, or notices. It's not always good to suppress errors (especially with @), but on a live box I'd say its fine.

Comment: Thanks @PhpMyCoder. Besides that, you can just suppress Notices, they won't hurt. Besides, you can always read them from the logs. I'm sure you won't show errors in production-environments (do you?), you show your own abstract error ("Oops, something went horribly wrong ...") instead of showing an error which contains a raw piece of code.

Comment: this is not the point.  in development stage those errors mean something, and sometimes notices also indicates programm errors, design flaws or point to unexpected/unknown bugs.
obviously he is new to php and should learn to produce good and clean code.